# How to solve 404 Error in AWS apg-get for debian jessie fetch?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, debian-jessie

I have a Linux AWS machine and i started having this issue a few days ago:

```
Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages


Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages


Err http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found

100% [5 Packages 9098 kB]Fetched 10.1 MB in 1s (7356 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Exited with code 100
```

my CircleCI config.yml errors out here (on install aweswebsli):

```
- run:
      name: Install awsebcli
      working_directory: ~/
      command: |
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip
        sudo easy_install --upgrade six
        sudo pip install urllib3==1.21.1
        sudo pip install awsebcli==3.14.11
```

some solution suggest modifying

```
/etc/apt/resources.list
```

but i can't find this folder/file on my AWS Linux.

Other posts suggest replacing this line

```
sudo apt-get update
```

with

```
apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

without success. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with Amazon or with your CircleCI configuration.
Jessie's repos have moved to debian's archive and you need to update the following file:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

The new content needs to be:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main
```

For more detailed information see this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1417656/918567).

Comment: thanks @Fanatique. i will consider this the right answer. i just cant find this folder on my machine.

Comment: @user3930696 you can't find `/etc/apt`?