# Issue with fetching http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease with docker

Tags: debian, docker

Im trying to run the command
docker-compose build

I get this output:

```
Step 4/8 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
 ---> Running in ee9551cd38b9
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease

Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [44.9 kB]

.....

Get:9 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9098 kB]

W: Fetched 10.1 MB in 6s (1519 kB/s)
Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
ERROR: Service 'webpack' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Anyone who has an idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apt-get update is failing in debian](https://superuser.com/questions/1417617/apt-get-update-is-failing-in-debian)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1420231/how-to-solve-404-error-in-aws-apg-get-for-debian-jessie-fetch

Comment: It says file does not exist.. Even the folder "apt" is not there, under /etc

Comment: Your system doesn't have or need it; the Docker container you're building does.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

I ran into this problem too this morning. I was able to solve it by combining advice from the following two tickets:

[How to solve 404 Error in AWS apg-get for debian jessie fetch?](https://superuser.com/questions/1420231/how-to-solve-404-error-in-aws-apg-get-for-debian-jessie-fetch)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406847/docker-how-to-add-backports-to-sources-list-via-dockerfile

**The solution:**

In your `Dockerfile`, before running any `apt` commands, add the following line:

```
RUN printf "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main\ndeb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main" > /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This enables `apt` to run from the new sources.

It's possible the `debian:jesse` Docker image will be updated to work correctly in the near future, but until then this will allow you to keep working

Comment: Thanks! Just ran into the same issue today. This seemed to work in my case.

Comment: Note that https://superuser.com/a/1424377/172047 does not require any change in your `Dockerfile`

Comment: Worked for me, but needed do add dns as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991136/docker-build-could-not-resolve-archive-ubuntu-com-apt-get-fails-to-install-a

Comment: `jessie-updates` was merged into `jessie`. Keeping it was useless. Jessie is still supported via `security.debian.org`. More on it [here](https://www.lucas-nussbaum.net/blog/?p=947). Or see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508728/29867) answer.

Answer (score 21):

[The debian team has fixed it](https://github.com/debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts/issues/66). Pulling the image again so that it gets updated fixed it for me:

```
docker pull debian:jessie
```

Warning from the linked ticket:

> Also, please migrate off Jessie ASAP -- the clock is ticking!!

Comment: If this fix does not work, try `docker pull debian:8`

Answer (score 6):

### My solution

#### Quick workaround

Overwritting `sources.list` is not what I want:

```
sed '/jessie-updates/s/^/# /' -i /etc/apt/sources.list
```

will just comment lines containing `jessie-updates` and keep everything else!

> ```
> deb http://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib
> deb-src http://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib
>
> deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
> deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
>
> # # jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
> # deb http://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
> # deb-src http://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
> ```

So I continue to use local mirrors while *`Debian jessie`* stay supported.

#### Upgrade to *stretch*

Then for upgrading to stretch, I just

```
sed 's/jessie/stretch/' -i.jessie /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This will create a *`source.list.jessie`*

then I can uncomment *`stretch-updates`* lines:

```
sed '/stretch-updates/s/^# //' -i /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 2):

The better solution would be to use build-pack images in your docker containers for jessie so you can do something like :

```
FROM buildpack-deps:jessie
```

You can get them [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/buildpack-deps)